# How to refresh kendo grid data source in angular js?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, kendo-grid

I am trying to update my kendo grid data source. But i am getting this [image: error]

```
$("#Cart").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data.refresh(); //Inside button click event
 <div kendo-grid="ItemCartGrid" options="ItemCartGridOptions" id="ItemCart">
dataSource: {
                pageSize: 10,
                data: $scope.data
            },
```

How do i reload my grid when i click on a button.

Comment: Your code example is unclear. How have you bound the click event? How are you referencing the options object? Make a fiddle that replicates the problem otherwise your question is too ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

```
function refreshData() {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#Cart').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
}
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer.

Comment: The function can be used in a button **<input type="button" value="Refresh Grid" onclick="refreshData();">**

Comment: That's kind of obvious. What I meant was: explain why your call to `read()` mitigates the problem presented in the question, i.e. why would the exception not be thrown in your case?

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you post the server response to see the return answer, but I suspect that it is single element, that is why you get this error, slice function does not exist. In such case it is best to investigate the data inside the dataSource object and if it is single element to set it to array, because Kendo dataSource works only with array of data. add this schema configuration to the dataSource object:

```
schema: {
        data: function (result) {
            if ($.isArray(result)) {
                return result;
            }
            else {
                return [result];
            }
        }
    },
```

this should do the work.